# Submitting an HTML form to PHP using JQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I was wondering if there was a succinct way to submit a form to my backend with JQuery AJAX (async). What I mean, more specifically, is:

HTML Form:

```
<form method="post" action="/Intranet/Resources/Forms/WorkOrder.php">
    <input type="text" name="notes[]" />
    <input type="text" name="notes[]" />
    ...
    <!-- a whole bunch more input fields here -->
</form>
```

This form is pretty awkward to separate into a bunch of variables with JQuery. I don't want the user to be redirected away from the page - I want the form to submit asynchronously. It's actually a save button...

Would it be better to screw it and just use JSON?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"save.php",
            type:"post",
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            success: alert('saved');
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('form').serialize()` to serialize a form. The result (for your form) would be:

```
notes=val1&notes=val2
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 1):

jQuery Serialize...

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Use it like so....

```
$.post("test.php", $("#testform").serialize());
```